# Adding a name to fields in a newly created data frame

Tags: r

I have created a new `data.frame` from another `data.frame`, for example:

```
aaa=cbind(bb1[,1],bb1[,2],ay,ax)
```

I want to name `bb1[,1]` as prob, `bb1[,2]` as recommendation and remaining as it is. Can someone tell me the syntax of doing this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You mean to name the column? You can use that when specifying the vector: `aaa <- data.frame(prob = bb1[,1], recommendation = bb1[,2],ay,ax)`

Answer (score 0):

```
bb1 = data.frame(c(1:10),c(11:20))
ax = c(21:30)
ay = c(31:40)
aaa = data.frame(cbind(bb1[,1],bb1[,2],ay,ax))
colnames(aaa) = c("prob", "recommandation","ax","ay")
```

Output

```
aaa
   prob recommandation ax ay
1     1             11 31 21
2     2             12 32 22
3     3             13 33 23
4     4             14 34 24
5     5             15 35 25
6     6             16 36 26
7     7             17 37 27
8     8             18 38 28
9     9             19 39 29
10   10             20 40 30
```